# Update table on Spring Batch Failure

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to update employee status based on input received from thirdparty API. Can anyone help me how can I update status of employee in EMPLOYEE table if step fails with some exception and overall job status to FAILED to my table instead of spring batch tables?

Comment: what is the format of the input received from the 3rd party API? Does the API return one employee status per call or does it return a collection of employees statuses?

Comment: it returns collection of employees statuses per api call

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed in two steps:

- step1 (tasklet): make the rest call and save the result in a file (remove the file after the job if necessary)
- step2 (chunk-oriented): read employee items and update their statuses in the database

For the writer, you can use a `JdbcBatchItemWriter` configured with a sql statement like: `update table employee set status = ? where id = ?`.

As per the step failure question, if any exception occurs during the processing of a chunk, the transaction will be rolled back and no updates will be committed to the database. More details about this in the reference documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#databaseItemWriters).

Hope this helps.